# Force node to require coffeescript by default

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

It's possible to use coffeescript files without compiling it on node, not directly of course but after importing "cofffee-script/register". I am wondering though if it's possible to feed coffeescript file to node directly, forcing it to import "coffee-script/register" by default? so I could do this from the command line

```
node debug my-app.coffee
```

Maybe somehow tweaking `require.cache`?

Comment: Isn't that what the `coffee` command is for? e.g. `coffee my-app.coffee`

Comment: yeah but what about debugging?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean how do you enable the debugger, or are you asking about sourcemaps or something? You didn't really mention debugging in your question beyond the one word, so I wasn't sure what you wanted.

Comment: you can't fire node debugger with `coffee`, can you?

Comment: You can do `Like `coffee --nodejs --debug-brk my-app.coffee` and run a debugger separately. Are you expecting a debugger REPL where you can also run coffeescript, or just to debug a coffeescript program?

Comment: I want the same behavior as it would run transpiled js file through node with debugger enabled - `node debug my-app`. Currently `coffee --nodejs --debug-brk my-app.coffee` says "debugger listening on port 5858" and does nothing else - no REPL, nothing